# Allow pinch zoom in a webview in spite of user-scalable=no is set in viewport meta

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, pinchzoom

I'm accessing a webpage in Android web view on which I can't pinch zoom. I went through source code of that page and found following line in head.

```
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Is it possible to either modify this line before rendering or is there any web view settings which over-write this meta tag and allows pinch zoom.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the document's properties since the WebView respects those. This works for me:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');");               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Allow Pinch Zoom in WebView use:

```
  webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: @T.G.ALShammari Yes, I've already added given lines of code. But, I guess due to viewport meta tag of html with user-scalable=no, these web view setttings are avoided.